# npm install gives ERESOLVE errors even after version downgrade

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

UPDATE: I got over this by doing

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

But still am curious to know how to adjust my package.json

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: on-up-frontend@2.0.9
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=17" from @coreui/react@4.11.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@coreui/react
npm ERR!     @coreui/react@"^4.11.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   peer react-dom@">=17" from @coreui/react@4.11.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@coreui/react
npm ERR!     @coreui/react@"^4.11.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

Comment: share your package.json

Comment: @ALTHAFPJALEEL See https://gist.github.com/sureshvv/16661981226ef9cf4f4cdd57669af344

Comment: Are you sure you added the right package.json ? asking because in the link @coreui/react version is `^2.5.8` where as in the above error message it is `4.11.1`

Answer (score 1):

As per the above error message, you are using `react-dom@18.2.0` which needs `react@18.2.0`. But in your project, you are using `react@17.0.2`. This is causing a version mismatch and hence the error.

To fix this, install `react@18.2.0`